# How to become this fast with eclipse like this expert user?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

http://de.twitch.tv/mojang/b/308842196

The minecraft developer notch made a video (link above) where he was coding a game in eclipse.
He is very fast and i wonder how you would become this fast.
Is he using eclipse plugins to be this fast? It looks to me that he is just using the keaboard.

Comment: Learn to type very fast, and learn to use keyboard shortcuts and navigation.

Comment: He is just using the keyboard, and that's what most serious programmers do when coding (if possible). Try using vim for a while...

Comment: The auto-complete in IDEA is better (See Smart-Complete) and faster (although I think you can configure eclipse's default latency). It also has KeyMaps for eclipse if you are already used to eclipse. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html

Answer (score 1):

That's how fast every experienced Java developer used to Eclipse programs. The trick is to learn many keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you are interested in using Eclipse.  It is a powerful tool, but he is just using autocomplete and keyboard shortcuts.  One thing to remember is that actually typing code often takes a smaller percentage of time compared to design, testing, and bug fixing.

Here are some common shortcuts:
http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse3.html